# Why do I get NPE using Scala Enumeration with App mix-in?

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, enumeration

I have the following code describing enumeration:

```
package aicore2.worker.scheduling
    object Priority extends Enumeration with App {
      type Priority = Value

      /**
       * Action is performed immediately, any running action is interrupted
       * and action queue is cleared
       */
      val ACHTUNG = Value

      /**
       * Action is performed before all LOW, NORMAL and HIGHER actions
       */
      val HIGH = Value

      /**
       * Action is performed before all NORMAL and LOW actions
       */
      val HIGHER = Value

      /**
       * Standart priority for most actions
       */
      val NORMAL = Value

      /**
       * Action is added to the end of the queue. Desired for non-critical maintenance actions
       */
      val LOW= Value


      Priority.values  foreach println
    }
```

and a test:

```
package aicore2.worker.scheduling

import org.junit.Assert._
import org.junit.Test
import aicore2.worker.scheduling.Priority._

class PriorityTypeTests {

  @Test
  def toStringTest()  {
    //Priority.values  foreach println
    //Priority.main(Array("2"))
    assertEquals(HIGH.toString(), "HIGH")
  }

  @Test
  def stringParseTest() {
     assertEquals(Priority.withName("HIGH"), HIGH)
  }

}
```

When I run tests, I get NPE (HIGH=null).

When I run Priority as App, I get whatever I want:
ACHTUNG
HIGH
HIGHER
NORMAL
LOW

The same result and no NPE I get when calling Priority.main() before running test.
When I remove App trait mix-in  from Priority header ( "with App"), all tests are passed as expected.
I understand that there is something weird with initialisation order when I mix in the App trait, but I'm new to Scala (refugee from Java field) and have no enough experience yet to figure things out.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're mixing the app trait into your enum in the first place?  That seems a little odd to me.

Comment: No, I just copied an example from the manual and leaved an App to run foreach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App` means that the members don't get initialized until you run the `main` method. Try the following in the REPL:

```
object A { val x = "foo" }
object B extends App { val x = "foo" }
A.x // = "foo"
B.x // = null
```

In your Enumeration class with App, all the members are `null` until you call its `main` method. So `HIGH.toString()` from your test method causes a nullPointerException because `HIGH` has not been initialized.

It therefore seems like a very bad idea to give an `Enumeration` the `App` trait.

Comment: Thank you, I just adopted a standart Weekday example)) Have not reputation to vote yet)

Answer (score 1):

The `App` trait extends the `DelayedInit` trait, which delays the initialization of its member until it is explicitly requested (at the start of the application for the `App` trait). You should think of it as a main method made object.

For more informations about the `App` and `DelayedInit` trait, you can read the [Scala 2.9.0 release notes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9483).

Comment: Thank you, I just adopted a standart Weekday example)) Have not reputation to vote yet)